# In Pandas, how do I calculate the number of occurrences in a particular temporal range?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm looking at ER data and want to build a time series for the number of patients who arrive at the ER per hour.  My data set has patient arrival dates and times in one column (so Row 1 might have '1/12/13, 19:21:12', but converted to a pandas date range.

The data set itself is stored in a pandas DataFrame.  The column of dates in the DataFrame is stored as a Series.

How would I go about aggregating and storing the number of patient arrivals per hour and plotting them in a time series?  I'd like each data point to be something like "5 patients between 1PM and 2PM on January 15th".

Comment: I haven't been sure where to start.  Right now I have a column of a pandas data frame with all of the arrival times stored as a pandas datetime.  I'm a newbie when it comes to using pandas.  I was thinking this requires something involving groupby but I have no idea how to use it well.

Comment: just give us a sample dataframe.

Comment: >>> clean_data

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Int64Index: 20544 entries, 0 to 20543

Data columns:

row_id           20544  non-null values

day_of_week      20544  non-null values

date_time_in     20544  non-null values

date_time_out    20544  non-null values

date_in          11671  non-null values

date_out         20544  non-null values

weekday          11671  non-null values

month            11671  non-null values

date             11671  non-null values...

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as:

```
patients.set_index('arrival_time').resample('H', how='count').plot()
```